# Powershell - splitting strings on 2 different delimiters

Tags: string, powershell, split, directory

I have a list of file names & a separate file location in a text file that I would like to read into Powershell.  There are 2 columns in the input file separated by a comma.  The first column gives the full name of the file share including the filename & the second column has in it a partial path for an image file.  Example:

```
\\myshare\backup\work\folder1\file1.txt,..\image\image1.tif
\\myshare\backup\work\folder2\file2.txt,..\image\image2.tif
\\myshare\backup\work\folder2\file2a.txt,\image\image3.tif
```

The difference is that the items with `..` preceding the image folder are relative to where the `file_.txt` is located.  In the example above -

```
\\myshare\backup\work\image
```

would be a folder on the same level as `folder1` & `folder2`. Both `image1.tif` & `image2.tif` would be in the above folder.  The one without the preceding `..` would be a sub-folder of the folder the file is in.  The file `image3.tif` would be in this folder:

```
\\myshare\backup\work\folder2\image\image3.tif
```

I'm reading the text file as follows:

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\username\Documents\workfile.txt" | foreach {
$fn, $location = $_.Split(',')
}
```

It splits it okay, but I need to split the `$location` variable again on the slashes (`\`).  I would like to do one thing if it has the `..` and something different if it doesn't.

How do you split a string a second time (on another character) within a `foreach` loop that you have already split the string?  I've tried a couple different things, but each has  given an error message and does not run.  One message is "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline."  If I try to split it again (inside another `foreach` loop) it loses the values in both `$fn` & `$location` variables.

Comment: It's called `Import-CSV` and `Split-Path` .. You're doing too much

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the 'split' operator once again, this time on the $location string, inside the foreach loop, to split each 'part' of the $location string into an array.  Then, you can examine the element zero of the array to see if it contains "..", like so:

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\username\Documents\workfile.txt" | foreach {
  $fn, $location = $_.Split(',')
  $locationparts= $location -split "\"
  #$locationparts[0] is now the first part of the location string, e.g. ".." 
}
```